# Please help with EclipseIDE message: "No appropriate file located or no file selected. Debug Terminated"

Tags: eclipse

I'm always getting this message in alert box.
Please tell me what should I do to avoid it?

Thank you

Comment: What are you doing when this happens?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. While I was writing this comment I get 2 messages http://img2.pict.com/ff/cd/cd/3293413/0/screenshot2b140.png ; I can't understand what Eclipse is talking about. :) I've tried to restart Eclipse, reboot... Nothing helps.

Comment: As soon as this alert appears <terminated><unknown> in debug window appears http://www.pict.com/view/3293497/0/screenshot2b141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I was getting this message and my solution see here
[XDebug, how to disable remote debugging for single .php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570680/xdebug-how-to-disable-remote-debugging-for-single-php-file)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you've added PHP support to your project and have adjusted your PHP Include Path Source such that the project is contained within the Source directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been having this problem, and I do not want to disable remote debugging.

After fruitlessly trying many different combinations of configuration, I tried deleting my Eclipse project and recreating it. Now the project debugs perfectly!

I guess my project (which is large and quite old) has become somehow corrupted or tangled. I only tried it because a newer project was debugging fine, so I was pretty sure my settings were right. I hope this helps someone.

Update:
You also get error this if you are missing project include path under your project settings: PHP Include Path > Source.

Answer (score 0):

create a new project with path settings the folder at the source of your project ( that includes all your project files )