# How to turn off xdebug in script?

Tags: php, xdebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable XDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754826/how-to-disable-xdebug)

I have installed xdebug, but it is making my unit tests much slower. Is there a way to disable it via `ini_set` or other way. I tried `xdebug_disable()`, but no difference at all, unless I change php.ini file.

My idea is to turn on xdebug only when code-coverage report is generated, I don't need it before that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570680/xdebug-how-to-disable-remote-debugging-for-single-php-file

Comment: @zod: that's for remote debugging

Comment: [ApiGen](http://apigen.org/) also takes incredible amounts of memory when generating documentation if xdebug is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I didnt check but maybe

```
xdebug_start_code_coverage();
```

and

```
xdebug_stop_code_coverage();
```

work for you

found it here
http://xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage

Comment: Tried that, doesn't change anything. Still slow